# Google Calendar CalDAV time-range not working

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, caldav

I am trying to get all events within a time-range. This is my CalDAV request body:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<C:calendar-query xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
   <D:prop xmlns:D="DAV:">
      <C:calendar-data />
   </D:prop>
   <C:filter>
      <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
         <C:time-range end="20200920T134847" start="20200919T134847" />
      </C:comp-filter>
   </C:filter>
</C:calendar-query>
```

As can be seen, I use the time-range component filter.
Unfortunately, this also returns events outside the time-range:

```
...
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20200522T111028
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20200522T121028
...
```

Can anyone see what is going wrong?

I saw [this](https://github.com/caldav4j/caldav4j/blob/c9957d75078d03b0f76e5fdee41d2a6b7d114e24/src/test/java/com/github/caldav4j/methods/CalDAVReportTest.java#L121) and [this](https://icalendar.org/CalDAV-Access-RFC-4791/7-8-1-example-partial-retrieval-of-events-by-time-range.html) example which puts the `VEVENT` comp-filter within a `VCALENDAR` comp-filter like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<c:calendar-query xmlns:c="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" xmlns:d="DAV:">
   <d:prop>
      <d:getetag>
         <c:calendar-data>
            <c:comp name="VCALENDAR">
               <c:prop name="VERSION">
                  <c:comp name="VEVENT">
                     <c:prop name="SUMMARY">
                        <c:prop name="UID">
                           <c:prop name="DTSTART">
                              <c:prop name="DTEND">
                                 <c:prop name="DURATION">
                                    <c:prop name="RRULE">
                                       <c:prop name="RDATE">
                                          <c:prop name="EXRULE">
                                             <c:prop name="EXDATE">
                                                <c:prop name="RECURRENCE-ID" />
                                             </c:prop>
                                          </c:prop>
                                       </c:prop>
                                    </c:prop>
                                 </c:prop>
                              </c:prop>
                           </c:prop>
                        </c:prop>
                     </c:prop>
                  </c:comp>
                  <c:comp name="VTIMEZONE" />
               </c:prop>
            </c:comp>
         </c:calendar-data>
      </d:getetag>
   </d:prop>
   <c:filter>
      <c:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
         <c:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
            <c:time-range start="20060104T000000Z" end="20060105T000000Z" />
         </c:comp-filter>
      </c:comp-filter>
   </c:filter>
</c:calendar-query>
```

So I tried the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<C:calendar-query xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
   <D:prop xmlns:D="DAV:">
      <C:calendar-data />
   </D:prop>
   <C:filter>
      <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
         <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
            <C:time-range end="20200920T135938" start="20200919T135938" />
         </C:comp-filter>
      </C:comp-filter>
   </C:filter>
</C:calendar-query>
```

But then Google gives the following error message:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
 <error>
  <domain>GData</domain>
  <code>badRequest</code>
  <internalReason>Bad Request</internalReason>
 </error>
</errors>
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

//update:

I tried [the example from icalendar.org](https://icalendar.org/CalDAV-Access-RFC-4791/7-8-1-example-partial-retrieval-of-events-by-time-range.html), which seems to work. The only problem is that I can't replicate that request body with caldav4j.

I also tried to copy the exact example from caldav4j:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<C:calendar-query xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
   <D:prop xmlns:D="DAV:">
      <D:getetag />
      <C:calendar-data>
         <C:comp name="VCALENDAR">
            <C:comp name="VEVENT">
               <C:prop name="SUMMARY" />
               <C:prop name="UID" />
               <C:prop name="DTSTART" />
               <C:prop name="DTEND" />
               <C:prop name="DURATION" />
               <C:prop name="RRULE" />
               <C:prop name="RDATE" />
               <C:prop name="EXRULE" />
               <C:prop name="EXDATE" />
               <C:prop name="RECURRENCE-ID" />
            </C:comp>
            <C:comp name="VTIMEZONE" />
            <C:prop name="VERSION" />
         </C:comp>
      </C:calendar-data>
   </D:prop>
   <C:filter>
      <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
         <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
            <C:time-range end="20200920T161921" start="20200919T161921" />
         </C:comp-filter>
      </C:comp-filter>
   </C:filter>
</C:calendar-query>
```

Unfortunately it gave another badRequest response.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I ended up switching to another CalDAV server (Radicale) for server-side logging. It turned out that the time notation should end with a "Z".